# Importing GeoJSON data to babylon JS | Rendering 3D Map

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, babylonjs

I'm trying to render a 3D map based on [OSMbuildings](https://osmbuildings.org/) in Babylon JS and apply on the map physics engine(3D spheres). In this case the ground has to be the map.

I took a look about that, I see after creating the ground I need to diffuse Texture using the tiles url (as it's shown on this [example](https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#1XBLWB#240) line 45).

My point is to have also the buildings on the ground, so probably there is way how to import the geojson data. Does anybody know how to do that? let's say I want to load

http://a.data.osmbuildings.org/0.2/anonymous/tile/16/35210/21492.json